# Custom 404 page image?

Tags: discussion

It looks like the 404 images for SE sites can be community generated. MVM&R currently uses the [default 404 image](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/404). Of the ones I've looked at, my personal favorite is the [Server Fault 404 image](https://serverfault.com/404), so I just wanted to see if the community might be willing provide something more clever than just an image with 404 or "page not found" in it.

Comment: Just wanted to throw in that [Bicycles](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/404) also has a good 404 image.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that sites can have custom error and human identification images too - for example, Film&TV's [error](http://movies.stackexchange.com/error) and [human identification](http://movies.stackexchange.com/captcha) images

Comment: For the human identification, all I can think of is Bumblebee. http://www.musclecarszone.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/8633087_3.jpg

Comment: @Paul [I am incapable of happiness. But I will say that it is logical that you are here.](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/knightrider/images/9/96/KITT2000.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20080209010753&path-prefix=en)

Comment: @JasonC LOL... that one didn't occur to me! I guess I latched on to the BumbleBee image because might not be a robot, though that might make more sense if the car were driving on a road with the driver seat somehow obscured from view.

Answer (score 5):

Well, we'd have to get permission / check licensing for any images we use, but to get some trains of thought started:

### Abandoned auto shops:

(My personal favorite theme for a 404 page)

[image]
([image source](http://weburbanist.com/2015/09/06/fender-bender-menders-15-abandoned-auto-body-shops/) -- there's other pics here but I picked this one because it's nameless)

### Old engines:

My second favorite:

[image]
([image source](http://wallpaperstock.net/broken-engine_wallpapers_10510_1280x800_1.html) - a [cropped version](http://automotiveguru.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/BrokenEngine_zps09218c83.jpg))

### Broken parts:

[image]
([image source](http://www.triumphrat.net/speed-triple-forum/122490-t509-can-you-identify-this-broken-engine-part.html))

[image]
([image source](http://www.dieselduck.info/historical/01%20diesel%20engine/Doxford/damage/))

### Broken / old / rusted out cars:

[image]
([image source](http://xqua.deviantart.com/art/The-broken-car-314635340))

[image]
([image source](https://www.pexels.com/photo/broken-car-vehicle-vintage-2071/))

[image]
([image source](http://panopticon-stock.deviantart.com/art/Broken-car-3-373322863))

### Vintage cars

A Model T:
[image]
([image source](http://salvationlinks.com/model-t-ford-a-real-bargain/))

### Large collections of tools

(It's too bad this photo isn't conspicuously missing one socket.)

[image]
([image source](http://jpegbay.com/gallery/000976141-2.html#2))

---

I'm also searching for pics of messy / disorganized shops, no luck yet.

Other ideas that might inspire you:

- Do a Google Image Search on any of the above images for related ones.
- Extremely complicated engines.
- Radiators blowing up in people's faces (but without injury, of course).
- Comical road-side situations.
- Stock photography of engine parts.
- Etc.

Comment: I think the abandoned garage is good concept since 404 means "not found" or "wrong address". But maybe not an auto body shop. I found an image that the site hosting is also the person who took the image as part of a hobby, so maybe would could get permission. http://www.lightrainproductions.com/images/Misc%20Photos/2009%20Jan/SanJon10.jpg

Comment: @Paul Agreed; the issue is without a sign on the shop, it's just a plain old abandoned building and loses some of its meaning, but I could only find examples of abandoned body shops. I want to take a picture of one locally but I tend to be in cities where abandoned shops don't stick around. I wonder if one of the users here has any abandoned shops nearby and would be willing to contribute a photo.

Comment: How did my linked image look to you?

Comment: @Paul Good vibe but not clear that it was a service station (stupid tree, good building but bad angle). Check out http://bit.ly/2dcdJ7h (not sure if that'll work; it's a link to a Google Image related image search result), there's a bunch there. I kinda like http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-abandoned-repair-shop-or-garage-for-vehicle-repairs-13313320.jpg or https://infinitebeginningsdgw.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/abandoned-garage/. I wish that body shop one wasn't such a perfect, clear building. Maybe I could photoshop "Body" into "Repair" or something.

Comment: If we had anyone in the community good with image editing software, this kind of a edit would probably only take 15 minutes to either add or change while still looking very believable.

Comment: I just noticed that the Auto Body image has a watermark in it.

Comment: It might be easier to add text to images with no text. I don't have a Pinterest account, but there is an image I found there that also looks good to me. https://www.pinterest.com/pin/17944098488614088/ It is also here: http://media-cache-ec0.pinimg.com/736x/e5/3e/ee/e53eee566ccc34fb8c4ecdf74d4c35fe.jpg

Comment: @Paul Yeah, my original intent for this post was just to inspire other suggestions, not to find immediately usable images. If we wanted to use that first image, for example, we'd have to get permission from Brook Tyler, possibly ask permission to use it without a watermark, possibly have a meta discussion about leaving the watermark, make sure none of that conflicts with SE content licensing terms, yada yada. Later, when I've got more time, I'll start looking for free public domain images that can be used right away. User-contributed original photographs would be awesome, too.

Comment: Right. Better to first find some agreement on image concept, then nail down specific candidate images, then worry about details of using one.

Comment: Most of these are nice pictures, but I don't see the connection with a 404 page. Maybe a car with an empty engine bay?

Comment: @tlhIngan That would be a great one, too. As far as these images, to me the abandoned shop and rusted out cars have a clear connection. The old engines and broken parts are only suggestive of alone-ness / failure but are not strongly connected. The vintage cars and tool sets aren't really connected at all, they're just generic images, if folks want to swing that way. Mostly I just posted these to get a conversation started since nobody had replied yet. Empty engine bay would be a good one!

Answer (score 5):

### Something along the lines of a CEL

Sample pictures for illustrating the concept

[image: Dashboard]

[image: Dashboard 2]

[image: Oil Pressure]

Comment: I think this makes sense for the error page (see comment on question).

Comment: @Paul agreed...

Comment: Not all Motor Vehicles have these.

Answer (score 4):

### OBDII equivalent of a 404

As an added bonus, the same concept can be extended to other HTTP codes.

[image: P0404]

[image: P0404 2]

Comment: Cute, but I'm reading it as p0404.

Comment: I think this is too clever.

Answer (score 4):

I think this image does it for the 404:

[image]

It does the job and straddles the line between the car world and the internet.

EDIT:

Here it is with a little photochop magic:

[image]

Comment: It's funny. A little ... meme-y. But a crowd pleaser, and does the job well. +1; What about if the "CAR NOT FOUND" text was removed? The subtlety might be pleasant.

Comment: I agree ... I could take the "car not found" out and not even miss it ... in fact I can probably photochop it when I get a chance.

Comment: Well I've already got Photoshop open so: [Cropped](http://i.imgur.com/OHG7pcc.jpg), [cut](http://i.imgur.com/KOiAvAP.jpg), or [cloned away](http://i.imgur.com/QyoUGEz.jpg), pick your poison. I left the little MemeCenter.com link on the side, too early to be handling attribution.

Comment: I like this one. Funny.

Answer (score 3):

I would love to see some Laurel & Hardy photos

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: YES! These are awesome.

Comment: Loverly, but copyright probably stops these from being usable.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's one of my faves:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Some Stooges (they're pretty much endless with a Google search)

[image]
([image source](http://j-walkblog.com/index.php?/weblog/comments/35312))

[image]
([image source](http://thecimmerian.com/2015/10/13/academic-wankery-and-the-rise-of-the-uninformed/))

Comment: I think the Knuckleheads Garage one would be problematic as they are using a derivative of the Harley-Davidson "bar and shield" logo. Obviously not original 3 Stooges artwork.

Comment: @Paul Good point; probably not the best idea.

Comment: These might be better suited for error pages, too, although in that case I like Zaid's dash light suggestion a little better.

Comment: We'd need permission from the copyright holder for re-use.